# Imagemagick convert from AI to bmp degrades color density

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using imagemagick to convert AI to bmp/png/gif/svg I can see the vector to vector conversion remains same color quality/density but the rasterized files seems loosing the color density.
AI file:

[image]

bmp file:
[image]

It's not the whole command but I use similar to `convert -density 1200 input.AI -quality 100 output.bmp`

I use linux os with IM 6 version. Due to copy right restriction I could not provide the AI file directly. I am wondering is there is any inherent drawback of loss of color density if we convert Vector files into Raster format.

Comment: Post a link to your AI file (not a png copy). What is your version of IM and what platform.

Comment: updated the post now. IM6 and linux. my inability to share the entire file. sorry.

Comment: Why can you not zip the AI file and post the zip file? What is the exact version of your IM 6.

Comment: These symbols go to an embedded industrial product so cannot reveal softcopies here. Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101.

Comment: Try finding the part in the AI file where the green colour is specified and share that if you can. Try showing your complete command as `-quality 100` is superfluous so maybe there are other *"sub-optimal"* things in your command causing the issue.

Comment: Exact command I run from the location where AI file resides : convert -density 300 ai:- -resize 894x894 output.bmp.

Comment: A little caveat : I use imagemagick 6 version installed in a docker container with ubuntu in windows OS.

Comment: can you run identify -verbose <your_vector_file>? Is the colorspace CMYK? does it have an embedded color profile? If it's in CMYK, did you try to add a -colorspace CMYK flag to your command? (so that the BMP would become CMYK instead of SRGB). BTW, I don't think density or quality has anything to do with what you are experiencing.